# Redeclare function (override)

Tags: functions

What is the best method, to change the previously declared function into the new one?

for example, there is already declared:

```
function smth(){
echo 'aaa';
}
```

and i want that it displayed not **aaa**, but **bbb**

```
function smth(){
echo 'bbb';
}
```

but when i insert the new function (*inside functions.php*), i get error message

`(Fatal error: Cannot redeclare **smth()** (previously declared in ... )`

## UPDATE - I have found a solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125517/2165415

Answer (score 4):

PHP cannot redeclare functions. You will need to use some other approach, like filters or similar.

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't allow to redeclare functions. If you write the original function, there aare a lot of ways to allow you to write a more flexible functions.

Conditional on passed arguments and filter hook, are first that comes into my mind.

EX. 1:

```
function smth( $out = 'a' ){
  if ( $out === 'a' ) {
    echo 'aaa';
  } else {
    echo 'bbb';
  }
}
```

After that, first time call

```
smth();
```

and second time:

```
smth('b');
```

---

EX. 2

```
function smth(){
  echo apply_filters('my_smth_filter', 'aaa');
}
```

After that, first time call

```
smth();
```

and second time:

```
add_filter('my_smth_filter', function() {
  return 'bbb';
});
smth();
```

---

If the original function is **not** function of yours and it doesn't provide any filter to change output and you *absolutely* need to change that function behaviour, then look at [Patchwork](https://github.com/antecedent/patchwork), a PHP library that lets you redefine user-defined functions at runtime.
However use Patchwork with caution and only if *absolutely* necessary, because Patchwork is intended to be used for testing purpose, not on production.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use OOP approach, like:

```
class SomeClass
{
  public function aa()
  {
     echo 'aa';
  }
}

class SomeOtherClass extends SomeClass
{
   public function aa()
   {
      return 'bb';
   }
}

$a = new SomeClass();
$a->aa(); // outputs aa
$b = new SomeOtherClass();
$b->aa(); // outputs bb
```